# processamento de imagens (classificador KNN) - python

Tags: python, array, matriz, processamento-de-imagens, deep-learning

Ao utilizar o KNeighborsClassifier, estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
/Feature Extraction (Python)/KNNpy:58: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  knn.fit(trade_conj, trade_label)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Feature Extraction (Python)/KNNpy", line 61, in <module> 
pred = knn.predict(features[i, :])#processo KNN
  File "\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_classification.py", line 171, in predict
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
  File "\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 556, in check_array "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Estou trabalhando com uma matriz *"features"* (22x2048) proveniente do processo de extração de características.

e um array *"labels"* 1x22 representando os rótulos.

*trade_conj*=*"features"* e *trade_labbel*=*"labels"*

não tenho intimidade com o python, porém, este código é uma "tradução"(?) de outro código em matlab que utiliza o mesmo array e matriz e funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema ai é com a dimensão dos parâmetros que você está passando. Sem os dados e o código que você usou fica difícil saber exatamente o que fazer, mas tente começar pela sugestão que o erro te dá, use:

```
knn.fit(trade_conj, trade_label.ravel())
```

Pois assim o seu Y_train será um vetor plano, e também:

```
pred = knn.predict(features[i, :].reshape(-1,1))
```

Assim você terá um array 2D (um "matriz" de uma única coluna) , pois `features[i, :]` te retorna um array 1D.

Diferentes funções requerem parametros em formatos diferentes, com tempo você acostuma. Espero ter ajudado, se não, por favor compartilhe a parte do código que dá esse problema e os dados para que seja possível testar.

EDIT:

Exemplo de array 1D: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Exemplo de array 2D:[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]] ou [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

Comment: era isso mesmo, consegui resolver o problema com:

`Y_training = Y_training.values.ravel()`

Obrigado !